# How to debug postgres syntax error at or near

Tags: postgresql, docker-compose, postgres-10

I have a postgres 10.6 container running with docker-compose.
I have tried to use the command to create a user but it's not working.

```
docker-compose exec kong-database psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE ROLE joe PASSWORD 'md5b5f5ba1a423792b526f799ae4eb3d59e' SUPERUSER CREATEDB CREATEROLE INHERIT LOGIN;'
```

Also,

I am getting this error

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "md5b5f5ba1a423792b526f799ae4eb3d59e"
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE joe PASSWORD md5b5f5ba1a423792b526f799ae4eb3d59e...
                                 ^
```

Also,

```
docker-compose exec kong-database psql -U postgres -c 'CREATE ROLE davide LOGIN PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4' '
```

Same error,

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "jw8s0F4"
LINE 1: CREATE ROLE davide LOGIN PASSWORD jw8s0F4 
                                          ^
```

Apparently when I don't use `WITH PASSWORD` or `PASSWORD` in the command, it goes through. But I must secure the db with a password.

What is wrong?

Comment: The password needs to be enclosed in single quotes, so if you pass it as a value inside single quotes you need to escape them.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I don't understand. If I escape them with by doubling them up I still get the same error

Comment: That escaping is done on the command line (run by the docker command) not in SQL

Answer (score 1):

The single quotes around the password are getting eaten by the shell, before PostgreSQL ever sees them.  You need to escape them somehow.

One way would be to quote your entire command using shell double quotes rather than single quotes, as single quotes occuring inside double quotes are not special.

```
 psql  -c "CREATE ROLE davide2 LOGIN PASSWORD 'jw8s0F4'"
```

but if your password contains characters which are special inside shell double quotes, like dollar signs, that will be a problem.  (so just make the password longer, and exclude any such characters from it)

> If I escape them with by doubling them up I still get the same error

doubling quotes is how you escape them inside SQL, but that is not how you escape them in the shell.  The problem is that your single quotes are not getting into SQL in the first place because the shell eats them.

If the shell double quotes for the whole command don't work for you, the other way you escape single quotes in the shell is with a backwhack.  The problem is that the backwhack inside single quotes does not work as an escape, so you have to close the single quotes, backwhack a single quote, then reopen the single quotes, then repeat that whole thing at the other end.  Also, for testing purposes you can replace `psql -c` with `echo`, so that you can see what the shell is going to pass into psql without actually running it.

```
echo 'CREATE ROLE davide3 LOGIN PASSWORD '\''jw8s0F4'\'' '
```